# I want to make item in table clickable

Tags: php, html, search, codeigniter-2

I make search function and I want make row in my table clickable, and after user click that row, I want get that data and use it in query, so I can show another table from that query. can someone help me?

[image: I want that ticket row clickable]

Answer (score 0):

Use a  element inside.

For example

```
<tr>
  <td><a href="#">Something</a></td>
</tr>
```